# iOS 4.2 - What's there for the iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have looked at iOS 4.2 wrap-ups and all I can see are features for iPad.

Besides AirPrint (which does not work with my printer), is there anything for the iPhone 3GS there?

Comment: i think eventually air print will work on printers  connected  to macs and with software for windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among other things:

- *Free “Find my iPhone” (don’t need MobileMe)* **—> this requires an iPhone 4**
- Safari allows you to search inside the page
- You can assign different SMS/MMS/ALERTS to different phonebook contacts
- AirPlay / AirPrint?
- A volume slider control in the Multitaskbar
- New icon for Voice Memos
  -

Anything else?

**UPDATE**: There’s a trick to use the *Find my iPhone* in a 3GS or similar. I found out that if you create everything from an iPhone 4 (and/or presumably an iPod TOuch latest gen), you can later go to your 3Gs and enter the same data and it will work. :)

Comment: Hmmm, kind of slim pickings.

Comment: Martin, how's that find my iphone trick again? "create everything"?

Comment: @Cawas you have to create the account and configure it from an iPhone 4 (with the app Find My Iphone). So all the steps you have to perform as if you had an iPhone 4.

Comment: Oh, that's a very interesting trick! Thanks for sharing it! :)

Answer (score 1):

new Calendar application with among other things, new birthday icon